# Como buscar dados tendo a véspera da data como parâmetro?

Tags: mysql

Não tenho erro no meu código, minha pergunta é bem simples:

como referenciar no where de uma query que a busca deve ser feita pelos dados da véspera ao dia corrente?

por exemplo, se tenho dados armazenados com a data 21/11/2019, eu preciso que no dia 20/11/2019 seja exibida na tabela os dados referentes ao meus serviços do dia seguinte

eu simplesmente não sei como referenciar isso no campo where, já tentei algumas coisas mas os resultados não foram o esperado

```
SELECT 
    employees.id_employee AS idemp,
    employees.nome AS nome,
    GROUP_CONCAT(customers.nome
        ORDER BY period) AS nome2,
        GROUP_CONCAT(customers.id_customer
        ORDER BY period) AS id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(customers.adress
        ORDER BY period) AS address,
        GROUP_CONCAT(customers.phone
        ORDER BY period) AS phone,
        GROUP_CONCAT(events.id_event
        ORDER BY period) AS idevent,
        GROUP_CONCAT(events.price
        ORDER BY period) AS price,
        GROUP_CONCAT(events.frequence
        ORDER BY period) AS freq,
        GROUP_CONCAT(events.period
        ORDER BY period) AS period,
        GROUP_CONCAT(events.date
        ORDER BY period) AS dia

FROM
    events
        INNER JOIN
    employees ON employees.id_employee = events.id_employee
        INNER JOIN
    customers ON customers.id_customer = events.id_customer
    WHERE employees.id_employee=events.id_employee AND events.date > CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY employees.nome
ORDER BY nome ASC
```

aí está minha query, no where eu preciso que busque apenas a data da véspera, e não todas as datas maiores que a atual

Comment: Eu acredito que já existe uma pergunta similar em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572083/grab-where-curdate-and-the-day-before-with-mysql . Neste caso, WHERE employees.id_employee=events.id_employee AND events.date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) resolveria. OBS: Não testei.

Comment: Tente:  `WHERE employees.id_employee=events.id_employee AND events.date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`.